# How to replace Hidden component in Material-ui V5

Tags: material-ui

I have some Hidden components below:

```js
<Hidden smUp>
  ...
</Hidden>

<Hidden xsDown>
  ...
</Hidden>
```

It's deprecated in V5. So how can I use Paper & Box components as in the migration documents?

Sorry but it's quite difficult to follow the guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Migration from v4](https://next.material-ui.com/guides/migration-v4/#hidden) documentation, this is actually pretty good explained.

You have to replace

```js
<Hidden smUp>
  ...
<Hidden/>
```

with

```js
<Paper sx={{ display: { xs: "block", sm: "none" } }}>
  ...
</Paper>
// or
<Box sx={{ display: { xs: "block", sm: "none" } }}>
  ...
</Box>
```

and

```js
<Hidden xsDown>
  ...
</Hidden>
```

with

```js
<Paper sx={{ display: { xs: "none", sm: "block" } }}>
  ...
</Paper>
// or
<Box sx={{ display: { xs: "none", sm: "block" } }}>
  ...
</Box>
```

### Live demo:

[image: Edit mystifying-bouman-c788k]